# how to run spring boot jar using forever

Tags: spring-boot, forever

My application jar package is ready. i can start application using below.

`java -jar myapp.jar &`

is forever run this spring boot application.?

`forever java -jar myapp.jar`

Comment: Hope this help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589082/spring-boot-takes-like-forever-to-start-up-in-openshift

Comment: pm2 is a process tool that is very useful to run spring-boot applications forever in the background. also providing easy monitoring and load balance configuration to the application.

    pm2 start "java -- -jar build/app.jar" --name boot-api